# errors.Is(...) are not symmetric?

Tags: go

I tried to find right way to comparing `errors` and found some *strange* behavior

```
type errorOne struct{}

func (e errorOne) Error() string {
    return "Error One"
}
```

```
e1 := errorOne{}
e2 := fmt.Errorf("E2: %w", errorOne{}) // return 'error' interface
res1 := e1 == e2          // false
res2 := errors.Is(e1, e2) // false
res3 := errors.Is(e2, e1) // true
```

It's look like that `errors.Is(...)` aren't symmetric (or I don't understand the method behavior).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`errors.Is()`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) is **not** an "equals" implementation, but rather an "is-it-wrapped" check.

`e2` wraps `e1`, but `e1` doesn't wrap `e2`. So why would `errors.Is()` be symmetric? "Wrapping" is a one-way relation; e.g. there is a mother-daughter relation, but the mother of the mother is not her daughter.

A wrapped error may be wrapped by another, creating a "chain". `errors.Is()` basically tells you if a given error is part of that "chain".

Note that you may "extract" the wrapped error using [`errors.Unwrap()`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Unwrap), e.g.:

```
fmt.Println(e2)
fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(e2))
fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(errors.Unwrap(e2)))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4xc5DrK3qIK)):

```
E2: Error One
Error One
<nil>
```

The third line is `<nil>` because `errors.Unwrap(e2)` returns `e1` (more specifically a copy of `e1`), and it doesn't wrap any errors.

Read blog post for more details: [The Go Blog: Working with Errors in Go 1.13](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors)

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is):

> Is reports whether any error in err's chain matches target.
> The chain consists of err itself followed by the sequence of errors obtained by repeatedly calling Unwrap.

So while you can unwrap `e2` to retrieve `e1`, if you unwrap `e1`, `e2` is not in the chain.